# Javamail: IMAP: Content-type of mails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

We are using JavaMail (IMAP) to access emails. Usually the mails have the content-type "multipart/...". Today we fetched a mail which was of content-type application/pdf and the message was a base64 encoded PDF.

I was surprised that his is possible. Is this the expected behavior? If yes, is there a way to make sure that for mails containing only a attachment, it will be delivered as multipart mail?

Comment: There are no restrictions in the specifications for what types may or may not appear.  The sender system can format it however it wishes.  Having the only part not being a `text/` part is perhaps unusual, but within specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible and allowed by the relevant standards ([RFC-2045](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045), [RFC-2046](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2046) and others). The only way to ensure this doesn't happens is if you control the sender and make sure their emails are structured like you want.

If you are not in control of the sender, you need to be prepared to handle everything that is structurally valid according to the RFCs.

In it's simplest form, an email has an envelope and a single part. This is usually a content-type text/plain or text/html with the 'body' of the email, but that is not required. In this case, the sender only sent a PDF (as body or attachment), and sent it in the top-level envelope with content-type application/pdf.

Only if a message needs to have multiple parts (e.g. a body and one or more attachments), will it have a multipart (e.g. multipart/mixed) (or more nested multiparts).

Comment: Technically, the application/pdf could very well be the body of the message and not an "attachment" at all. PDF would be a perfectly suitable format to use for formatted text and images, after all.

Comment: @jstedfast True, though as far as I'm aware, most mail clients wouldn't be able to handle PDF and still handle it as if it is an attachment. I'll see if I can reword.